# Manual loading or display of Google Ads banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adsense

I have a mobile single page web application. I have a container which should hold my Google Adsense ad, however I don't want it to be displayed right away, instead it should appear after the user has done a specific amount of browsing in my app.

My first approach to achieve this was a container like this:

```
  <div id="googlead" class="nodisplay">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
      <!-- pinkstar_user -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
    data-ad-client="xxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="xxxxx"></ins>
    <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>
```

The idea was to load the ad on pageload but have the container hidden with `display: none` (that's what the css class does) and remove this class later to make it visible.

However this approach didn't work as the ad is never rendered when using `display: none`

My second approach was to load the ad myself in a function like this:

```
function setAdContent() {
    var googlead = $("#googlead");
    var userdetail = $("#userDetails");
    userdetail.css('display', 'none');
    googlead.css('display', 'inline-block');
    window.google_ad_client = "xxxxxxx";
    window.google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxx";
    window.google_ad_width = 336;
    window.google_ad_height = 280;

    var w = document.write;
    document.write = function (content) {
        googlead.innerHTML = content;
        document.write = w;
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    adCounter = 0;
}
```

This approach didn't work either because Google does not want people to refresh ads and therefore only allows the calls on pageload, so the ad is not rendered again.

I'm kinda stuck and wanted to ask for ideas and how I can solve this. I was thinking of trying some kind of iframe approach, but maybe somebody has a better solution.